# Syscall alternative for printf()?

Tags: c, system-calls

I'm wondering what would be a syscall alternative to the **printf()** function?
For example, a function that does exactly the following?

```
char message[256] = "Hello";
printf("Message is : %s\n", message);
```

I have tried **write()**, but it doesn't take format specifiers.

Comment: Why would someone have written `printf` if there was already a handy syscall to do the same thing?

Comment: `puts` isn't a syscall. No syscall exists for `printf`-like output formatting.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I need a function that uses format specifiers, and it has to be a syscall

Comment: Moreover, the very concept of syscalls is implementation-specific, and on many implementations they're not even stable public interfaces you can use directly from an application, so this question isn't a meaningful without specifying a *particular implementation* (probably Linux) rather than generic `c` plus `unix` tagging.

Comment: @MisterTusk: That's still an XY problem. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve by having such a thing?

Comment: System calls are for things that require kernel support. `printf`-style formatting can be done in user mode, so it is done in user mode. (There is similar formatting code in the Linux kernel, for example, but it's not exported to user mode as a syscall.)

Comment: @MisterTusk Sorry, you're not getting one.

Comment: It's for a project where I am only allowed to use syscalls. And I need format specifiers? So I guess that is my problem :D

Comment: @John3136 Why would someone post a comment if it was not answering my question?

Comment: You have to implement the format specifiers by using `write`. Look at the source code of my `printf` to figure that out: https://github.com/JL2210/minilibc/blob/master/src/stdio/vfprintf.c  Alternatively, you can look at `musl` (but it is a bit complicated for just learning): https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/vfprintf.c

Comment: @MisterTusk: Comments are not intended to answer the question. They're intended to ask for clarification or for *limited* discussion.

Comment: @MisterTusk: Yes. If this is homework, which it sounds like it is, then figuring out how to process a format string and convert the arguments is likely the whole point of the assignment.

Comment: @MisterTusk Either the assignment you've been given is impossible **or** you are expected to write your own code to do the formatting. I'd bet on the latter. For example, implementing your own `printf`-like function that doesn't depend on any library functions and that performs its output using only system calls might be a reasonable assignment.

Comment: There's no such thing as a system call that takes format specifiers. You could use three `write()` calls to implement your example, though.

Comment: @FredLarson Thanks, that would solve my problem, didn't think of that

Answer (score 2):

A question about syscalls needs to be in the context of a particular implementation (OS/kernel), since the very concept of syscalls is not universal but implementation-specific, and many operating systems do not even have them as a stable public interface you can use from applications. I'm going to assume you're asking about Linux where the question has the greatest chance of making sense.

So to answer your question, there is no such syscall. Syscalls are generally for performing input and output, changing the state of a process, and performing other operations that require crossing privilege domains or process contexts. It's rare for a syscall to exist to perform a task which is purely computational, and converting a format string plus a number of arguments corresponding to the format specifiers into a sequence of bytes is *purely computational*.

If you're willing to write the code to do the formatting yourself, you can of course write the output via the `write` syscall.